# ¿Como obtener un una variable de una Activity en el RecyclerAdapter de un RecyclerView?

Tags: android

Tengo un problema para llamar una variable que está en mi MainActivity hacia un RecyclerAdapter 
La variable la llamo así:

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
String userName = main.userName;
```

Pero me devuelve como null
En mi MainActivity la declaro así:

```
public String userName;
```

Y en el método onCreate():

```
userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
setUserName(userName);
```

No se que tenga mal
Les dejo mi [Repositorio](https://github.com/Topi99/Votaciones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás creando un nuevo objeto (MainActivity) e intentado acceder a un elemento que no existe en ese objeto. Tienes varias opciones, la más simple de todas es pasarle esa variable directamente al adaptador ya que la estás recogiendo antes de crearlo. Para ello, una opción sería:

Cambiar el constructor del adaptador por:

```
   public RecyclerAdapter(List<Partido> partidos, String username){
        this.partidos = partidos;
        this.username = username;
    }
```

Y cuando lo crees en el MainActivity:

```
adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(partidos, username);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si en la `MainAcivity.java` ejecutas el `RecyclerView`, lo que haría seria pasar esa variable por el constructor del `RecyclerAdapter`:

En tu `RecyclerAdapter` creas una variable global que guarde el valor de la variable que le pasas y creas un constructor:

```
private String userName;

public RecyclerAdapter(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
```

Y en tu `MainActivity.java` lo inicializas así:

```
private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
public String userName;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        setUserName(userName); // No se para que servirá en tu código,
                               // si aplicando esto te sigue devolviendo 
                               // null, miraría a ver si me borra el valor.

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(userName);

        [...]

    }
```

Y así ya la puedes utilizar la variable en tu `RecyclerAdapter`.

En caso de que ese `RecyclerAdapter` lo reutilices en otras partes de tu código, puedes crear un constructor vacio y así poder elegir si pasarle o no datos.

Espero que te sirva.

Suerte!!

Answer (score 0):

LA respuesta de amendezcabrera te explica muy bien porque está null, otra posible solución es pasando la actividad por el constructor del adaptador:

**Actividad:**

```
   adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, partidos);
```

**Adapter:**

```
  MainActivity activity;
  PartidosDataSource dataSource;
public RecyclerAdapter(MainActivity activity, List<Partido> partidos){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.partidos = partidos;
    Log.i("LOGTAG", "En recycler adapter: " + partidos.toString());
}
```

Entonces ya puedes hacer `String userName = activity.userName;` sin problema.

Si necesitas usar el mismo adaptador para varias actividades puedes hacerlo así:

**Adapter:**

```
  Activity activity;
  PartidosDataSource dataSource;
public RecyclerAdapter(Activity activity, List<Partido> partidos){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.partidos = partidos;
    Log.i("LOGTAG", "En recycler adapter: " + partidos.toString());
}


String userName = (MainActivity)activity).userName;
```

Un saludo.